# Mongo DB Compass Error on importing .json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am trying to import the json file in to my mongo db with MongoDBCompass and its showing me this error,

[image: MONGO COMPASS ERROR]

This is how the data in my json file looks like,

```
  {
    "computing" :
  [
 {
   "year": "Hour of Code",
   "unit": "Hour of Code lessons ",
   "topic": "Drawing with code",
   "name_of_the_video": "Welcome to our Hour of Code™!",
   "ID": "Video",
   "video_duration": "2:16",
   "youtube_ID": "CYmL-Up_ZNc"
 },
 {
   "year": "Hour of Code",
   "unit": "Hour of Code lessons ",
   "topic": "Drawing with code",
   "name_of_the_video": "Learning coding on Khan Academy",
   "ID": "Article",
   "video_duration": "",
   "youtube_ID": ""
 }
],
"computing2" :
[
{
 "year": "Hour of Code",
 "unit": "Hour of Code lessons ",
 "topic": "Drawing with code",
 "name_of_the_video": "Welcome to our Hour of Code™!",
 "ID": "Video",
 "video_duration": "2:16",
 "youtube_ID": "CYmL-Up_ZNc"
},
{
 "year": "Hour of Code",
 "unit": "Hour of Code lessons ",
 "topic": "Drawing with code",
 "name_of_the_video": "Learning coding on Khan Academy",
 "ID": "Article",
 "video_duration": "",
 "youtube_ID": ""
}
]
}
```

I can't understand why I just cannot pass the array in that json file, I have validate my json and is perfectly ok. Can I get some help in this? what thing I am doing here is wrong?

Comment: have you tried wrapping those documents in `[]` so the file contains an array of documents?

Answer (score 0):

remove the key "computing" and pass it like this (as a plain array) :

```
    [
 {
   "year": "Hour of Code",
   "unit": "Hour of Code lessons ",
   "topic": "Drawing with code",
   "name_of_the_video": "Welcome to our Hour of Code™!",
   "ID": "Video",
   "video_duration": "2:16",
   "youtube_ID": "CYmL-Up_ZNc"
 },
 {
   "year": "Hour of Code",
   "unit": "Hour of Code lessons ",
   "topic": "Drawing with code",
   "name_of_the_video": "Learning coding on Khan Academy",
   "ID": "Article",
   "video_duration": "",
   "youtube_ID": ""
 }
]
```

Comment: I want that key as well in my data

Comment: mongodb json import, would populate a collection for you. so it should accept a collection (or an array) , do you want to name the collection "computing"? or you have a list of computing objects?

Comment: list of computing object and then list of computing object 2 named as computing2 then computing3 and so on

Comment: I have edit the question @fatemeh for better understanding

Comment: ok then pass it like this : `[{computing1:[{"year":1996,...},{"year":1969,...}]},{computing2:[{"year":1997,...},{"year":1998,...}]]`